Docker login in gitlab pipeline/job timeout error: dial tcp: lookup registry.gitlab.com on 127.0.0.53:53
Since last week, the gitlap pipeline has been failing without any changes to the code or infrastructure.
I have two gitlab groups, each with its own registered-gitlab runner. The gitlab runner (version: 16.9.1) is used by both groups. Both groups use the same deployment which was created with gitlab-ci and ansible. For group 1 the pipeline runs without problems, for group 2 it fails with the docker login message:
TASK [role-mysql-deployment : Log into private registry and force re-authorization] ***
fatal: [targethost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["docker", "login", "-u", "gitlab-ci-token", "-p", "[MASKED]", "registry.gitlab.com"], "delta": "0:00:30.023206", "end": "2024-06-12 10:56:55.503736", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2024-06-12 10:56:25.480530", "stderr": "WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.\nError response from daemon: Get \"https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry.gitlab.com on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:46776->127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout", "stderr_lines": ["WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.", "Error response from daemon: Get \"https://registry.gitlab.com/v2/\": dial tcp: lookup registry.gitlab.com on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:46776->127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

Gitlab-Runner config.toml
[[runners]]
  name = "gitlabcom-runner-1"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "<token>"
  executor = "docker"
  environment = ["GITLAB_API_TOKEN=<api-key>"]
  output_limit = 16384
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "registry.gitlab.com/<custom-gitlab-runner-image>"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0

.gitlab-ci.yml from used runner image
stages:
  - build

docker_build_job:
  image: docker:stable
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY

  script:
  - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
  - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG

the pipeline has several jobs, the docker login works for the first jobs that run through, but not for the next ones
- name: Log into private registry and force re-authorization
  command: "docker login -u '{{ $CI_JOB_TOKEN }}' -p '{{ $CI_JOB_TOKEN }}' {{ $CI_REGISTRY }}"
  when : mysql_docker_deployment_state == "present"

I have compared all group configurations, validated access tokens and the runners, but I cannot find the error or the reason why the error occurred in a group

Cleared the runner cache
Changed priviliged to true
Took the newest the docker and dind images
Restartet the Runner Container

the error still occurs
